# JMS topic subscriber reconnection

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, jms-topic, openmq

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with OpemMQ 4.5.2 (remote mode). In my application, there is a subscriber of a JMS topic, that receives messages asynchronously, using a `MessageListener`.

When broker is stopped and started after a while, messages published to the JMS topic after restart are not received by the subscriber.

What is the best way to recover the topic subscriber?

I've tried `ExceptionListener`, but apparently it's not supported when running my application on Glassfish.

Comment: Changed "Reconnect Attempts" option from "Java Message Service" to "-1" and Glassfish successfully reconnected publisher and subscriber. Is this always guaranteed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed "Reconnect Attempts" option from "Java Message Service" to "-1" and Glassfish successfully reconnected publisher and subscriber.